# Copy files to the target directory after build

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Let's assume I have a game with the following directory structure:

```
/src
/resources
Cargo.toml
```

I would like `cargo build` to copy the files in the `resources` directory and paste them in the same directory as the executable file.

I know it is possible to do this using a custom build script, but this seems to be a common case that deserves special treatment. So the question is: **does cargo provide a standard way of copying files to the target directory (using just `Cargo.toml`)?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

You can move files around with [build scripts](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html), but these are run before your crate is built because their sole purpose is to prepare the environment (e.g. compile C libraries and shims).

If you think this is an important feature, you can open a feature request in Cargo [issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues).

Alternatively, you can write a makefile or a shell script which would forward all arguments to cargo and then copy the directory manually:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$(dirname "$0")"

if cargo "$@"; then
    [ -d "$DIR/target/debug" ] && cp -r "$DIR/resources" "$DIR/target/debug/resources"
    [ -d "$DIR/target/release" ] && cp -r "$DIR/resources" "$DIR/target/release/resources"
fi
```

Now you can run cargo like

```
% ./make.sh build
```

Comment: I opened an issue as you suggested. Here is the link if anyone is interested: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1759

Comment: There is one issue for this: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/545

Answer (score 10):

I can't solve this for crates (as the accepted answer says) but for a "single" binary that needed a file to run correctly, this works for me.

```rust
use std::env;
use std::path::Path;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=config.json");
    println!("cargo:warning=Hello from build.rs");
    println!("cargo:warning=CWD is {:?}", env::current_dir().unwrap());
    println!("cargo:warning=OUT_DIR is {:?}", env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());
    println!("cargo:warning=CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR is {:?}", env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap());
    println!("cargo:warning=PROFILE is {:?}", env::var("PROFILE").unwrap());

    let output_path = get_output_path();
    println!("cargo:warning=Calculated build path: {}", output_path.to_str().unwrap());

    let input_path = Path::new(&env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap()).join("config.json");
    let output_path = Path::new(&output_path).join("config.json");
    let res = std::fs::copy(input_path, output_path);
    println!("cargo:warning={:#?}",res)
}

fn get_output_path() -> PathBuf {
    //<root or manifest path>/target/<profile>/
    let manifest_dir_string = env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();
    let build_type = env::var("PROFILE").unwrap();
    let path = Path::new(&manifest_dir_string).join("target").join(build_type);
    return PathBuf::from(path);
}
```

This is a mess and I'm very new to Rust. Improvements welcome.

Comment: I think you would benefit from `OUT_DIR`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#outputs-of-the-build-script