# Can I perform a task after compilation is complete?

Tags: rust, compilation, rust-cargo, toolchain

I know that [`build.rs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) can perform tasks before the program compilation starts, so I can prepare whatever I want.

What if there's a task to be performed **after** the compilation is complete, as some sort of cleanup? Is there any way to do such a thing?

As a simple example: before compilation I want rename a file from `foo.txt` to `abc.txt` for whatever reason. Then **after** the compilation terminates I want to rename it back to `foo.txt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is nothing as of Rust 1.50. [RFC #1777 — Add Cargo post-build scripts](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1777) proposed this, but it was not accepted.

In the meantime, some crates make their own local Cargo third-party commands to mimic this. Documentation of one style of this can be found in the [cargo-xtask](https://github.com/matklad/cargo-xtask) repository. The TL;DR form:

1. Create a local binary crate that performs a build and whatever else you need.
2. Add a Cargo alias to invoke that crate.
3. Call your custom command: `cargo xtask build`.

See also:

- [Copy files to the target directory after build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31080757/155423)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up with my current setup, which is simply a shell script with `cargo build` among the commands. Too bad that RFC was not accepted. 

Comment: @rodrigocfd note that your shell script is likely less portable than the Rust solution (e.g. what happens on Windows?), which may or may not matter for your case.

Comment: You're right, it's not *that* portable. In my particular situation, I'm on Windows using MinGW, which does understand shell scripts, so it's fine. Also, I have no plans to distribute this project.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this, if you have a *workspace* project:

- Create a new cargo project in your workspace next to the one you want a post-build script for - say `thingamabob_post_build`
- Set a dependency *in the new project* on the one you want a post-build script for
- Put a `build.rs` in the new project
- Have it do whatever you want to be sure is done *after* the other project is built